# Empty Part files are created when executing the INSERT INTO SELECT statement in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have created a partitioned table in hive. Here is the statement.

```
Create table **my_table**( Column 1 , column 2, column 3 ) PARTITIONED BY(batch_date);
```

and I'm creating one more table

```
Create table **my_table1**( Column 1 , column 2, column 3 ) PARTITIONED BY(batch_date);
```

and I ran this statement

```
INSERT INTO TABLE my_table1(batch_date='2018-02-22')  select column 1, column 2, column 3 from my_table where column 1 = "ABC";
```

and it returned zero rows as I dont have any values with column 1 = "ABC";
**(returning zero records is not an issue)**

But my concern is as I have 3 columns in my `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement it is creating 3 empty part files in the hdfs directory. and I dont want these 3 part files to be created under my hdfs directory and I couldn't resolve it

and also before running the insert statements I did set the below hive properties but no use.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

Can someone please suggest me a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by setting properties hive.merge.mapredfiles=true hive.merge.size.per.task=256000000 hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=256000000
    And let's share your output.

Comment: I have set the above properties before running insert command. I still see  empty files are getting  created under batch_date partition       -rwxrwx--x+  3 hive hive          0 2018-02-22 11:34 /data/*/work/hive/Test_Partition2/batch_date=2018-02-22/000000_0 .added one empty partition for your reference